# hive: too many mappers were started

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I am using cdh 5.4.9 with hive version 1.1.0

I want to insert the data from an external table to the non-external table.

something like this

`INSERT INTO TABLE mytable SELECT * FROM mytable_tmp;`

the datasize from mytable_tmp is about 10 MB.

And the hdfs block size is 128 MB.

So the expected number of mappers would be 1.

However, it shows me 829 mappers, this is too large.

And hive throws such exceptions.

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load plan: hdfs://host:8020/tmp/hive/me/ea3b1570-db8a-4b55-a513-e3db5c4dae8b/hive_2016-01-06_17-51-25_558_6497985511241352149-1/-mr-10004/4a3f7801-fe47-4f23-9012-3a6b7a50d758/map.xml: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer underflow.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getMapWork(Utilities.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.init(HiveInputFormat.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(HiveInputFormat.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Buffer underflow.
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.require(Input.java:181)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readBoolean(Input.java:783)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.UnsafeCacheFields$UnsafeBooleanField.read(UnsafeCacheFields.java:120)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:507)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.deserializeObjectByKryo(Utilities.java:1069)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.deserializePlan(Utilities.java:960)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.deserializePlan(Utilities.java:974)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:416)
    ... 12 more
```

I think some configurations has mistakes, but I can not figure it out.

Is there any suggestions?

Thank you!